# Unable to construct and initialize viewModel

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am working on my first Xamarin application. I am trying to display my first page but getting following error on base.ViewDidLoad(); line in ViewDidLoad()

**MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxException has been thrown**

> Failed to construct and initialize ViewModel for type iManage.ViewModels.LoginViewModel from locator MvxDefaultViewModelLocator - check InnerException for more information

LoginView.cs:

```
public partial class LoginView : MvxViewController<LoginViewModel>
{
    public LoginView() : base("LoginView", null)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        txtUser.Layer.CornerRadius = 15;
        txtPassword.Layer.CornerRadius = 15;
        btnLogin.Layer.CornerRadius = 20;

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<LoginView, LoginViewModel>();
        set.Bind(txtUser).To(vm => vm.Username);
        set.Bind(txtPassword).To(vm => vm.Password);
        set.Bind(btnLogin).To(vm => vm.LoginCommand);
        //set.Bind(btnLogin).To(vm => vm.AttemptLogin());
        set.Apply();
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }
}
```

LoginViewModel.cs:

```
public class LoginViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private readonly ILoginService _loginService;

    private readonly IDialogService _dialogService;

    public LoginViewModel(ILoginService loginService, IDialogService dialogService)
    {
        _loginService = loginService;
        _dialogService = dialogService;

        Username = "TestUser";
        Password = "YouCantSeeMe";
        IsLoading = false;
    }

    private string _username;
    public string Username
    {
        get
        {
            return _username;
        }

        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _username, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Username);
        }
    }

    private string _password;
    public string Password
    {
        get
        {
            return _password;
        }

        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _password, value);
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => Password);
        }
    }

    private bool _isLoading;

    public bool IsLoading
    {
        get
        {
            return _isLoading;
        }

        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _isLoading, value);
        }
    }

    private IMvxCommand _loginCommand;
    public virtual IMvxCommand LoginCommand
    {
        get
        {
            _loginCommand = _loginCommand ?? new MvxCommand(AttemptLogin, CanExecuteLogin);
            return _loginCommand;
        }
    }

    private void AttemptLogin()
    {
        if (_loginService.Login(Username, Password))
        {
            ShowViewModel<DashboardEmpViewModel>();
        }
        else
        {
            _dialogService.Alert("We were unable to log you in!", "Login Failed", "OK");
        }
    }

    private bool CanExecuteLogin()
    {
        return (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Username) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Username))
               && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password) || !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Password));
    }
}
```

LoginService.cs:

```
public class LoginService : ILoginService
{
    /// <summary>Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="LoginService"/> class.</summary>
    public LoginService() // e.g. LoginService(IMyApiClient client)
    {
        // this constructor would most likely contain some form of API Client that performs
        // the message creation, sending and deals with the response from a remote API
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether the user is authenticated.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsAuthenticated { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>Gets the error message.</summary>
    /// <value>The error message.</value>
    public string ErrorMessage { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Attempts to log the user in using stored credentials if present
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns> <see langword="true"/> if the login is successful, false otherwise </returns>
    public bool Login()
    {
        // get the stored username from previous sessions
        // var username = Settings.UserName;
        // var username = _settingsService.GetValue<string>(Constants.UserNameKey);

        // force return of false just for demo purposes
        IsAuthenticated = false;
        return IsAuthenticated;
    }

    /// <summary>The login method to retrieve OAuth2 access tokens from an API. </summary>
    /// <param name="userName">The user Name (email address) </param>
    /// <param name="password">The users <paramref name="password"/>. </param>
    /// <param name="scope">The required scopes. </param>
    /// <returns>The <see cref="bool"/>. </returns>
    public bool Login(string userName, string password, string scope)
    {
        try
        {
            //IsAuthenticated = _apiClient.ExchangeUserCredentialsForTokens(userName, password, scope);
            return IsAuthenticated;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException argex)
        {
            ErrorMessage = argex.Message;
            IsAuthenticated = false;
            return IsAuthenticated;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Logins the specified user name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userName">Name of the user.</param>
    /// <param name="password">The users password.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool Login(string userName, string password)
    {
        // this simply returns true to mock a real login service call
        return true;
    }
}
```

Setup.cs:

```
public class Setup : MvxIosSetup
{
    public Setup(IMvxApplicationDelegate applicationDelegate, IMvxIosViewPresenter presenter) : base(applicationDelegate, presenter)
    {

    }

    protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
    {
        return new App();
    }
}
```

I have used [this url](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples/tree/master/XPlatformMenus) to implement it.

**Edit1:**
[image: Exception Detail]

**Edit2:**
**Inner Exception:**

> MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to construct and initialize ViewModel for type iManage.ViewModels.LoginViewModel from locator MvxDefaultViewModelLocator - check InnerException for more information ---> MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxException: Problem creating viewModel of type LoginViewModel ---> MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxIoCResolveException: Failed to resolve parameter for parameter dialogService of type IDialogService when creating iManage.ViewModels.LoginViewModel
>     at MvvmCross.Platform.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.GetIoCParameterValues (System.Type type, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo firstConstructor) [0x00066] in <6adc0d5857264558a9d45778a78ae02a>:0
>     at MvvmCross.Platform.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.IoCConstruct (System.Type type) [0x0002c] in <6adc0d5857264558a9d45778a78ae02a>:0
>     at MvvmCross.Platform.Mvx.IocConstruct (System.Type t) [0x00006] in <6adc0d5857264558a9d45778a78ae02a>:0
>     at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxDefaultViewModelLocator.Load (System.Type viewModelType, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle parameterValues, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedState) [0x00000] in :0
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxDefaultViewModelLocator.Load (System.Type viewModelType, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle parameterValues, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedState) [0x00029] in :0
>     at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel (MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedState) [0x00035] in :0
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel (MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request, MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxBundle savedState) [0x00068] in :0
>     at MvvmCross.iOS.Views.MvxViewControllerExtensionMethods.LoadViewModel (MvvmCross.iOS.Views.IMvxIosView iosView) [0x0005f] in <6f99728979034e579bc72f6d53e5bc35>:0
>     at MvvmCross.Core.Views.MvxViewExtensionMethods.OnViewCreate (MvvmCross.Core.Views.IMvxView view, System.Func`1[TResult] viewModelLoader) [0x00012] in :0
>     at MvvmCross.iOS.Views.MvxViewControllerExtensionMethods.OnViewCreate (MvvmCross.iOS.Views.IMvxIosView iosView) [0x00001] in <6f99728979034e579bc72f6d53e5bc35>:0
>     at MvvmCross.iOS.Views.MvxViewControllerAdapter.HandleViewDidLoadCalled (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00007] in <6f99728979034e579bc72f6d53e5bc35>:0
>     at at (wrapper delegate-invoke) :invoke_void_object_EventArgs (object,System.EventArgs)
>     at MvvmCross.Platform.Core.MvxDelegateExtensionMethods.Raise (System.EventHandler eventHandler, System.Object sender) [0x00003] in <6adc0d5857264558a9d45778a78ae02a>:0
>     at MvvmCross.Platform.iOS.Views.MvxEventSourceViewController.ViewDidLoad () [0x00006] in <4467c42ffcc4478e847227b8e4af47fe>:0
>     at MvvmCross.iOS.Views.MvxViewController.ViewDidLoad () [0x00001] in <6f99728979034e579bc72f6d53e5bc35>:0
>     at iManage.iOS.Views.LoginView.ViewDidLoad () [0x00001] in /Users/pankajsachdeva/Projects/iManage/iOS/Views/LoginView.cs:18
>     at at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
>     at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5665/6857dfcc/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79
>     at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/5665/6857dfcc/source/xamarin-macios/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63
>     at iManage.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in /Users/pankajsachdeva/Projects/iManage/iOS/Main.cs:17

Comment: "check InnerException for more information", I don't see the `InnerException` in your question

Comment: Hi Camilo, how should I see the InnerException? I am sorry I am new to Xamarin.

Comment: Debug up to the point where the exception is thrown, in the debugger you'll see the exception details and the `InnerException` property has the actual error

Comment: I have just added a screen shot of it, please check

Comment: I found it, please check my latest update

Comment: Given the error message, it seems that you did not register `IDialogService` in the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must register the implementations of your services in the IoC container so that they can be resolved when needed. This can be done in two places in general:

For platform independent services in the `App.cs` in the `Initialize` method:

```
public class App : MvxApplication
{
   public override void Initialize()
   {
      ...
      Mvx.ConstructAndRegisterSingleton<IDialogService,DialogService>();
      ...
   }
}
```

(Note that this should be done by default, because the default `App` class already contains a block that automatically registers all types with the "Service" suffix)

For a platform specific service in the platform's `Setup.cs` in the `InitializeFirstChance` method, for example for Windows it would be:

```
public class Setup : MvxWindowsSetup
{
   protected override void InitializeFirstChance()
   {
       Mvx.ConstructAndRegisterSingleton<IDialogService,DialogService>();
       base.InitializeFirstChance();
   }
}
```

I'm guessing the `DialogService` will be platform dependent, so the second solution will be more suitable.

You can use `LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton` to make sure the instance is created only when actually needed for the first time. You can also use `RegisterType` to just register the type and create a new instance each time it is needed.

More about MvvmCross IoC is [available in the documentation](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/inversion-of-control-ioc).

Comment: @pankaj  If this has resolved your issue, please consider accepting the answer as solution so that the question is resolved.